Configuring CORS for Specific Domains in Episerver 11
We are currently working with a React application that uses the Fetch API to retrieve documents stored in Episerver. However, we're encountering CORS errors. We have tried a couple of methods using the Web.config file, but they haven’t resolved the issue. Below are the approaches we’ve attempted:

Modifying Custom Headers & rewrite for outbound rules in Web.config
We modified the Web.config to add CORS headers, but it didn’t work as expected. Refer below xml changes. Unfortunately, this approach did not resolve the issue.

    <system.webServer>
  <cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true">
    <!-- Block all wildcard origins -->
    <add origin="*" allowed="false" />
    <!-- Specific allowed origins with credentials -->
    <add origin="https://site-dev.domain1.com" allowCredentials="true" maxAge="120" />
    <add origin="https://site-qa.domain1.com" allowCredentials="true" maxAge="120" />
    <add origin="https://site-uat.domain1.com" allowCredentials="true" maxAge="120" />
    <add origin="https://site-sandbox.domain2.com" allowCredentials="true" maxAge="120" />
    <add origin="https://site.domain2.com" allowCredentials="true" maxAge="120" />
    <!-- Allow localhost for local development -->
    <add origin="http://localhost:3000" allowed="true" />
    <!-- Block HTTP origins -->
    <add origin="http://*" allowed="false" />
  </cors>
</system.webServer>


2-Using CORS Module in Web.config
We installed the CORS module & configured it referring Cors-module-configuration. Refer below configuration. However, this approach caused issues, and the application stopped working.
    <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
    <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
    <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" />
    <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors 'self'; object-src 'none'; upgrade-insecure-requests;" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="{HTTP_ORIGIN}" /> 
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>

<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="setcorsheader">
      <match servervariable="response_access_control_allow_origin" pattern=".*" />
      <conditions logicalgrouping="matchall" trackallcaptures="true">
               <add input="{http_origin}" pattern="^(https:\/\/(site-(dev|qa|uat)\.domain1\.com|site-sandbox\.domain2\.com|site\.domain2\.com))$|^(http:\/\/localhost:3000)$" />

      </conditions>
      <action type="rewrite" value="{c:0}" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>

3- Another rewrite rule:
<rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="Add CORS Allowed Origins">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access-Control-Allow-Origin" pattern=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                           <add input="{http_origin}" pattern="^(https:\/\/(site-(dev|qa|uat)\.domain1\.com|site-sandbox\.domain2\.com|site\.domain2\.com))$|^(http:\/\/localhost:3000)$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_ORIGIN}" />
                </rule>

                <rule name="Add CORS Allowed Methods">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access-Control-Allow-Methods" pattern=".*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
                </rule>

                <rule name="Add CORS Allowed Headers">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access-Control-Allow-Headers" pattern=".*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="Content-Type, Authorization" />
                </rule>
            <rules>
             
            </rules>
        </rewrite>


This approach only includes Header &Methods. Origin is missing in the response header which is why CORS fails.

4- Current Workaround:
As a temporary solution, I have enabled CORS at the WebApp level via the Azure Portal (please refer to the attached screenshot for your reference).

I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to configure CORS in Episerver 11 for specific domains only.
There are settings available in Episerver 12 but I am looking for episerver 11.
